# Toggle function from variable

Tags: javascript, function, var

Let's say I have function `x.a()` and `x.b()`. I want to decide which function execute vía variable but it's not working my way. Here's my code and I hope you can help me.

```
var x = { 
    y: function(f, g){
        f(g);
    }
    a: function(txt){
        console.log(txt);
    },
    b: function(txt){
        console.error(txt);
    }
}
```

So when I call `x.y("a", "Some text");` it does the same as if i call `x.a("Some text");`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets to access an object's property by name:

```
var x = { 
    y: function(f, g) {
        this[f](g);
    },
    a: function(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    },
    b: function(txt) {
        console.error(txt);
    }
};
```

Comment: Both the OP code and yours are missing a comma after the declaration of `y` (for the record, I'm *not* the downvoter).

Comment: @minitech—perhaps the downvoter would rather cop the reputation hit than edit your post to add the comma (if that was the reason).